# Radio input not reflecting changes in AlertDialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter

So I am trying to have a simple form in a Dialog box in Flutter with one input field. The input can be interpreted in two ways so I have put a radio field to determine the type of input. Now the radio fields are not reflecting change in the UI even when the state is being updated. Checkout the screenshot below. No change occurs in selection when I select `Minutes`. I checked the state and it is being updated but not getting reflected in the UI.

[Screenshot for problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tAcK.png)

Here is what I have done. The dialog appears on click of a button.

**showDialog Function:**

```
Future<void> showSetTargetDialog(
    BuildContext context, TextEditingController targetController) async {
  return await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        int? type = 1;
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
          return AlertDialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
            // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            contentPadding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 16),
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: RadioListTile(
                          title: const Text('Pages'),
                          value: 1,
                          groupValue: type,
                          onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                                type = value;
                                print('Value is $value, type is $type');
                              })),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: RadioListTile(
                          title: const Text('Minutes'),
                          value: 2,
                          groupValue: type,
                          onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                                type = value;
                                print('Value is $value, type is $type');
                              })),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: targetController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration:
                      const InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter your goal"),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: const Text('Save'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
      });
}
```

Widget From which it is called:

```
class OnboardingSetTargetScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const OnboardingSetTargetScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _OnboardingSetTargetScreenState();
}

class _OnboardingSetTargetScreenState
    extends ConsumerState<OnboardingSetTargetScreen> {
  int? pages;
  int? minutes;

  TextEditingController _targetController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final devHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    final Widget onboardingSetTargetIllustration = SvgPicture.asset(
        Constants.onboardingSetTargetIllustration,
        height: devHeight * 0.6);

    final selectedBook = ref.watch(bookControllerProvider).selectedBook;

    final pages = ref.watch(onboardingControllerProvider).pages;

    final minutes = ref.watch(onboardingControllerProvider).minutes;

    void routeBack() {
      Routemaster.of(context).pop();
    }

    void updateTarget(String text) {
      ref.read(onboardingControllerProvider.notifier).setPages(int.parse(text));
    }

    String getSubtext() {
      if (pages != null) {
        return 'You have set your goal to read $pages pages per day';
      } else if (minutes != null) {
        return 'You have set your goal to read $minutes minutes per day';
      } else {
        return 'Tell us about your daily reading goals either in pages or minutes';
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 16.0, left: 16, right: 16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: routeBack,
              child: const Icon(
                FeatherIcons.chevronLeft,
                color: Pallete.primaryBlue,
              ),
            ),
            onboardingSetTargetIllustration,
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            const Text(
              'Set your goal',
              style: AppStyles.headingTwo,
            ),
            Text(
              getSubtext(),
              style: AppStyles.subtext,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: CustomButton(
                          text: 'Set Goal',
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await showSetTargetDialog(
                                context, _targetController);
                            if (_targetController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                              updateTarget(_targetController.text);
                            }
                          }),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: pages != null || minutes != null,
                      child: const SizedBox(
                        width: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: pages != null || minutes != null,
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Routemaster.of(context)
                              .push('/onboarding/select-time');
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                              color: Pallete.primaryBlue),
                          child: const Icon(
                            FeatherIcons.arrowRight,
                            color: Pallete.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It is working in my case

Comment: Still not working for me. What did you do?

Comment: I copied your snippet and run on  my machine, can you include full sample widget that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: Even when I tried the same piece of code in another app, it worked fine. So I have add the widget from which I am calling the dialog in the question.

Comment: Can you try with renaming `StatefulBuilder`'s setState to something else and then use that to call setState.I am not sure why it wont here in this snippet

Comment: I did. It didn't help. It is very strange. Were you able to reproduce?

Comment: create a new widget  and place this dialog snippet there, check if it produce this issue

Comment: I did. I created another screen with a stateless widget and used the dialog there. The issue still remained. But when I used it in a different project, it worked there.

Comment: Sorry I've failed to reproduce the issue, maybe  you can upgrade your package, restarting the pc etc.

Comment: So it worked when I put the code for the function directly in the widget and used the state in there.